# need to export access table to excel with automatic column width of 1 page

Tags: excel, ms-access, vba

I'm currently using a simple Access Macro which outputs a table from my Access database into an Excel spreadsheet.

That works fine, but I need it to export into Excel formatted so that it can be automatically printed with the columns fitted to one page (rows don't have to fit to one page).

Is this possible? I've searched numerous different times, but can't seem to find exactly what I'm looking for.

Comment: What size page do you want? I assume A4 portrait.

Comment: Yes, A4 is what I will use

Comment: How many columns do you want to fit across the page? Your title implies just one.

Comment: I will need 11 columns to fit on one page

Comment: Columns will have variable length of text in each record? Need to set wrapping? I expect will have to explicitly set column widths and wrapping. Why is this important in a spreadsheet? If you want to print, why not an Access report?

Comment: Good call on outputting to a report instead; I was over complicating it. The report worked fine and I was able to format the columns as I wanted. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Although it's probably not the most efficient approach, you can fit 11 columns onto an A4 page like this:

```
Sub aSubroutine()

    Dim Wkb As Workbook

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    Set Wkb = Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\JohnSmith\ExcelWorkbook.xlsx")
    Wkb.Worksheets("Sheet1").Columns("A:K").ColumnWidth = 6.57
    Wkb.Close savechanges:=True

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Obviously replacing `C:\Users\JohnSmith\ExcelWorkbook.xlsx` with the path of your worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

In Excel VBA:

```
With ActiveSheet.PageSetup
    .Zoom = False
    .FitToPagesTall = False
    .FitToPagesWide = 1
End With
```

(I see you have found another solution, but the above will be useful for someone else, I'm sure)